# Is there a 4-3 bass suspension?

Tags: nonchord-tones

This is a very common upper voice suspension but I was wondering if it is a thing in counterpoint or some classical styles to have it in the bass?

Comment: Please consider going back over your previous questions and voting for and/or accepting some of the answers. It's clear you're finding a great deal of value asking questions on the site.

Comment: yes sorry Aaron ,of course! :) I usually do but I must have forgotton on some of the last ones

Comment: Can't see much wrong with a *retardation* - often erroneously labelled a suspension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the only legitimate bass suspension is a 2-3 or its cousin 9-10, which is one octave higher.  The reason you can't have a 4-3 in the bass is that by rule suspensions resolve downwards.

If the bass were to strike a fourth with an upper voice (causing a dissonance), and then resolve down, the intervals would be 4-5.  If the bass were to form the intervals 4-3 by moving, it would be moving *up,* which would not be considered a proper suspension.

Note that this answer refers to the traditional counterpoint rules a la Fux and such.

Comment: Oh ok yes that makes sense so this would be a retardation right?

Comment: Yes, I think that is so.  But not in Fux; later on

Answer (score -2):

I'm tempted to disagree slightly with nuggethead's answer, and provide a slightly different perspective.

While technically there is no 4-3 suspension in the bass, there is a standard progression that simulates this pretty well, and it's the cantizans in bass, which is used a lot in classical music.

The progression is `I (6 4) 2 -- VII 6 5 -- I 5`. For instance in C major setting you could have:

`G    A    G      C`  
`E    F    F      E`  
`C    D    D      C`  
`C 5  C 2  B 6 5  C 5`

Of course, this isn't a 4-3 suspension per se, but the perception would be very similar as the C in the bass of the Dm7 inversion is very strongly leading to B, similarly as in Gsus4.

If you're brave enough, you could also do e.g. this, which would show the 4-3 suspension directly and be possibly acceptable in some styles: `II 7 (5) -- I 5 4 2 -- VII 6 5 -- I 5`. In pracice, it would be something like this, but you gotta be careful to avoid parallel 4th/5th:

`A    G        G      C`  
`F    F        F      E`  
`D/F  G        G      G`  
`D 7  C 5 4 2  B 6 5  C 5`

Comment: To be a 4-3 suspension, a fourth must resolve to a third through the downward motion of a voice.  This is impossible in the bass, because any downward movement would increase the interval to a fifth.  Your first example is indeed common, but it is a 2-3 suspension

Comment: @nuggethead Ok, point taken. We consider different vocabulary here it seems. If you consider vocabulary that the numbering is w.r.t. the bass, and not w.r.t. the chord's first, then you cannot have a suspension in the bass sort of by-definition, because the base is always 1. Then I think the question itself doesn't make _any_ sense. Or what do I miss then?

Comment: just show me where you have a 4th that turns into a 3rd when the bass moves and I'll accept your answer...